# Liferay DXP patching tool says "Won't be installed: Patch source code is not available"

Tags: liferay, patch, liferay-dxp

I installed Liferay DXP SP4, then downloaded and put `liferay-fix-pack-de-30-7010.zip` into Liferay's `patching-tool/patches/` folder, pacthed the Liferay server successfully to level 30, then edited `patching-tool/default.properties` that way:

```
patching.mode=source
source.path=/home/nico/liferay-dxp-digital-enterprise-src-7.0-sp4

war.path=../tomcat-8.0.32/webapps/ROOT/
global.lib.path=../tomcat-8.0.32/lib/ext/
liferay.home=../
```

When I run `./patching-tool.sh info` I get:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Loading product and patch information...
Product information:
  * installation type: source
  * build number: 7010
[Fatal Error] :120:26857: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
  * service pack version:
    - available SP version: Not available
    - installable SP version: Not available
  * patching-tool version: 2.0.6
  * time: 2017-10-31 06:59Z
  * plugins: no plugins detected

Currently installed patches: de-22-7010

Available patches: de-30-7010

Detailed patch list: 
  [ s] de-30-7010 :: Currently not installed; Won't be installed: Patch source code is not available :: Built for LIFERAY
```

Why does it say `Won't be installed: Patch source code is not available`?
What is wrong in my procedure described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there are two different fixpacks downloadable from Customer Portal, My best guess is that you downloaded "Fixpack 30" and not "Fixpack 30 Source Code". This would neatly explain the message `Patch source code is not available`. Just add the source fixpack to the patches directory.